# Using Wildcards with 'rename'

Tags: bash, unix, wildcard, rename

I have been using the `rename` command to batch rename files.  Up to now, I have had files like:

```
2010.306.18.08.11.0000.BO.ADM..BHZ.SAC
2010.306.18.08.11.0000.BO.AMM..BHZ.SAC
2010.306.18.08.11.0000.BO.ASI..BHE.SAC
2010.306.18.08.11.0000.BO.ASI..BHZ.SAC
```

and using `rename 2010.306.18.08.11.0000.BO. "" *` and `rename .. _. *` I have reduced them to:

```
ADM_.BHZ.SAC
AMM_.BHZ.SAC
ASI_.BHE.SAC
ASI_.BHZ.SAC
```

which is exactly what I want.  A bit clumsy, I guess, but it works.  The problem occurs now that I have files like:

```
2010.306.18.06.12.8195.TW.MASB..BHE.SAC
2010.306.18.06.14.7695.TW.CHGB..BHN.SAC
2010.306.18.06.24.4195.TW.NNSB..BHZ.SAC
2010.306.18.06.25.0695.TW.SSLB..BHZ.SAC
```

which exist in the same folder.  I have been trying to get the similar results to above using wildcards in the `rename` command eg. `rename 2010.306.18.*.*.*.*. ""` but this appends the first appearance of `2010.306.18.*.*.*.*.` to the beginning of all the other files - clearly not what I'm after, such that I get:

```
2010.306.18.06.12.8195.TW.MASB..BHE.SAC
2010.306.18.06.12.8195.TW.MASB..BHE.SAC2010.306.18.06.14.7695.TW.CHGB..BHN.SAC
2010.306.18.06.12.8195.TW.MASB..BHE.SAC2010.306.18.06.24.4195.TW.NNSB..BHZ.SAC
2010.306.18.06.12.8195.TW.MASB..BHE.SAC2010.306.18.06.25.0695.TW.SSLB..BHZ.SAC
```

I guess I am not understanding a fairly fundamental principal of wildcards here so, can someone please explain why this doesn't work and what I can do to get the desired result (preferably using `rename`).

---

**N.B.**

To clarify, the output wants to be:

```
ADM_.BHZ.SAC
AMM_.BHZ.SAC
ASI_.BHE.SAC
ASI_.BHZ.SAC
MASB.BHE.SAC
CHGB.BHN.SAC
NNSB.BHZ.SAC
SSLB.BHZ.SAC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rename` does not allow wildcards in the `from` and `to` strings. When you run `rename 2010.306.18.*.*.*.*. "" *` it is actually your shell which first expands the wildcard and then passes the result of the expansion to `rename`, hence why it does not work.

Instead of using `rename`, use a loop as follows:

```
for file in *
do
  tmp="${file##2010*TW.}"   # remove the file prefix
  mv "$file" "${tmp/../_}"  # replace dots with underscore
done
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try this first to see what commands would be executed

```
for f in *; do echo mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/2010.*.TW.//'` ; done
```

If it's what you expect, you can remove `echo` from the command to execute

```
for f in *; do mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/2010.*.TW.//'` ; done
```

Comment: Much appreciation for a complete answer including how to preview your commands.